# laravel 5.1 BelongsTo Reverse call

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5.1

What i know:

```
$this->$parent->childs(); //we get childs data
```

what i want to know how:

```
$this->child->find($id)->parent(); //how to get childs parent without including model in controller | by just using eloquent
```

heres my sample code of employee and employeeDependent model:

```
trait EmployeeRelationships{

    public function dependents(){
        return $this->hasMany(\App\DB\EmployeeDependent\EmployeeDependent::class);
    }

}

trait EmployeeDependentRelationships{

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function employee(){
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\DB\Employee\Employee::class, 'employee_id');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get the reverse of a `BelongsTo` relationship you need to specify the inverse of the relationship on the corresponding model. For example:

Employee Class

```
class Employee extends Model
{
    public dependents()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Dependant::class);
    }
}
```

Dependent Class

```
class Dependent extends Model
{
    public employee()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Employee::class, 'employee_id');
    }
}
```

With these relationships defined you can then access the relevant models by calling the appropriate methods like so:

```
$dependents = Employee::first()->dependents; // Returns an eloquent collection
$employee   = Dependent::first()->employee;  // Returns a model of type Employee
```

Note that in this example using the `first()` method to grab a model, you can can do this with any object of the correct type.

Comment: yes it works, but what im trying to do is i want get fetch dependents data, from dependentController(with employee id) without injecting employee model in it. is it possible? or im just doing it in wrong way.

Comment: this line works for me: $dependents = $this->employeeDependent->with('employee')->where('employee_id',$id)->get() but i injected employee model in dependentController.

Comment: Provided you have an object of type `Dependent` by calling `$dependent->employee` you will get an object of type `Employee`. You don't need to include the employee model or inject anything into the controller to do it.